# Getting Error - Ambiguous constructor error in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, constructor, dbcontext

I have two constructors in my dbcontext class. While running the code i am getting the following error

```
public NLGPaymentDBContext(
            IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
            ILogger<NLGPaymentDBContext> logger,
            IConfiguration configuration,
            DbContextOptions options) : base(options)

public NLGPaymentDBContext(DbContextOptions options, ITenantInfo tenantInfo) : base(options)


Error
The following constructors are ambiguous:
Void .ctor(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[NLG.Payment.Infrastructure.NLGPaymentDBContext], Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions)
Void .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions, Finbuckle.MultiTenant.ITenantInfo
```

How to resolve this ?

Comment: Just have one constructor?

Comment: is this a runtime error coming from the DI layer? in which case: which did you want the DI to use?